# Plug-in Registration Tool has stopped working

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

On Dynamics CRM 2015 Online, I have installed a Plugin Profiler using the Plugin Registration Tool provided in the SDK for CRM 2015.

When I start debugging using the profiler and Visual Studio 2013, the plugin profiler stops working with the error below when reaching at the point of code with suspected exception. Actual exception is not shown due to plugin error. Any ideas how to resolve this?

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

[Window Title]
Plug-in Registration Tool

[Main Instruction]
Plug-in Registration Tool has stopped working

[Content]
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

[Debug] [Close program]

I tried running the Plugin Registration Tool as an administrator also  but no difference.

Comment: Im always using PRT from SDK 2013 6.0, experiencing similar problems with PRT distributed with SDK2015.